# Triggering Lambda on basis of multiple files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm a bit confused, as I need to run an AWS glue job, when multiple specific files are available in s3. On every file put event in s3, I am triggering a lambda which writes that file metadata to dynamodb.  Here in dynamodb, I am also maintaining a counter which counts the number of required files present.

But when multiple files are uploaded at once, which triggers multiple lambdas, they write at nearly the same time in dynamodb, which impacts the counter; hence the counter is not able to count accurately.

I need a better way to start a job, when specific (multiple) files are made available in s3.

Kindly suggest a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamo is *eventually consistent* by default. You need to request a *strongly consistent* read to guarantee you are reading the same data that was written.

See [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html) for more information, or for a more concrete example, see the *ConsistentRead* flag in the [GetItem docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html).

It's worth noting that these will only minimise your problem. There will also be a very small window between read/writes where network lag causes one function to read/write while another is doing so too. You should think about only allowing one function to run at a time, or some other logic to guarantee mutually exclusive access to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are getting the current count, incrementing it in your Lambda function, then updating DynamoDB with the new value. Instead you need to be using [DynamoDB Atomic Counters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters), which will ensure that multiple concurrent updates will not cause the problems you are describing.

By using Atomic counters you simply send DynamoDB a request to increment your counter by 1. If your Lambda needs to check if this was the last file you were waiting on before doing other work, then you can use the return value from the update call to check what the new count is.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "specific" (multiple) files.

If you are expecting specific file names (or "patterns"), then you could just check for all the expected files as first instruction of your lambda function. I.e. you expect files: A.txt, B.txt, C.txt, then test if your s3 bucket contains those 3 specific files (or 3 *.txt files or whatever suits your requirements). If that's the case then keep processing, if not then `return` from the function. This would technically work in case of concurrency calls.

Comment: For some files only out of many, I need to increase the counter.Also I am not preferring to schedule the lambda, instead need to identify as soon as the file appears in s3.